# Why the "ambigous symbol" error in VS2010 for the code below?

Tags: c++, stream, forward-declaration

This code compiles in VS2010, and I believe it does for any compiler.

```
#include <iosfwd>
using namespace std;
class ostream;
int main() {}
```

The same happens with this code

```
#include <iosfwd>
using namespace std;
int main() { class ostream; }
```

But this code generates error C2872: 'ostream' : ambiguous symbol

```
#include <iosfwd>
using namespace std;
class ostream;
int main() { class ostream; }
```

Comment: [Don't use `using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

Answer (score 6):

There are two classes named `ostream` in scope: `::std::ostream` and `::ostream`. If you want to forward declare you have to do it in the correct namespace:

```
#include <iosfwd>
using namespace std;
namespace std {
    class ostream;
}
int main() { class ostream; }
```

Anyway, this won't work in this case because `ostream` is a typedef of `basic_ostream`, not a separate class. Just include the `iosfwd` header as it forward declares everything for you.